# NETBEANS 7.2 is not working

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

i installed netbeans 7.2 on windows 8, after that i double clicked on icon to start it, it displays loading cached objects and after 5 seconds it disappear with out opening any thing.
please let me know how to fix this problem.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please give more information:

1. What package of netbeans have you loaded?
2. Are you using a clean installation or have you imported settings from other installations?
3. Did you add any modules / plugins?
4. Have you made any changes?

Please have a look into your logfiles. You can find it in **`<NB user dir>/var/log/messages.log`**.

On windows 7+ it's usually here:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR NAME>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\<NETBEANS VERSION>\var\log\messages.log
```

A first thing you can try: Rename (so you can restore it again) your NetBeans user dir and start again. This will create a new directory with default settings. If it doesn't fail your problem is likely based on your settings.

Comment: rename user directory means?C:\Users\<YOUR NAME>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\<NETBEANS VERSION>\var\log\messages.log <YOUR NAME > in this case?

Comment: Rename this: `C:/.../AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/<Your netbeans version>`. So for 7.2 it's `C:/.../AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/7.0` i think. In this folder your settings are stored. So if you rename it you'll get a clean setup (but you can rename it back; that's why it's better not to delete it).